# Which of the given relations is also a function?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, relations

Which of the following relations are also a functions? $ S \subset R \times R $

1. $(x, y) \in S \iff x = y$ (mod 7)

   (2, 9) $\in S$ and (2, 16) $\in S$, so I assume this is not a function.
2. $(x, y) \in S \iff x = 0 \lor x = y$

   (0, 1) $\in S$ but also (0, 0) $\in S$, so I assume this is not a function too.
3. $(x, y) \in S \iff y^2 - x^2 = 16$

   (0, 4) $\in S$ but also (0, -4) $\in S$, so I assume this is not a function.
4. $(x, y) \in S \iff x^2 + y^2 = 1$

   (0, 1) $\in S$ but also (0, -1) $\in S$, so I assume this is not a function.

According to the definition of function, for all $x \subset X$ there exists only one $y$. Where am I wrong in given answers? At least one answer should be correct.

Comment: All of your reasoning is correct. Why do you think at least one answer is correct?

Comment: I am revising the past exam questions but I don't have the correct answer to all of them. Thank you for the answer, I guess then it is an error in the question.